# Phonegap build failing on OneSignal plugin

Tags: phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, phonegap

I'm just rebuilding my app due to needing a new distribution certificate. I get this error though:

```
"plugman-151 install --platform ios --project /project --plugin https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Cordova-SDK.git --nohooks=.": Fetching plugin "https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Cordova-SDK.git" via git clone
Using shallow clone
Repository "https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Cordova-SDK.git" checked out to git ref "master" at "9a9f4b2".
Installing "onesignal-cordova-plugin" at "2.6.0" for ios
"framework" tag with type "podspec" is deprecated and will be removed. Please use the "podspec" tag.
Running command: pod install --verbose
Failed to install 'onesignal-cordova-plugin': Error: pod: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/private/project/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
    at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:381:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Pipe._handle.close (net.js:611:12)
pod: Command failed with exit code 1
```

...and when doing it via **npm**:

> Error - Plugin error (you probably need to remove plugin files from
>   your app): //github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Cordova-SDK.git
>   --nohooks=.": Fetching plugin "https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Cordova-SDK.git" via git clone
>   Using shallow clone Repository
>   "https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Cordova-SDK.git" checked out
>   to git ref "master" at "9a9f4b2". Installing
>   "onesignal-cordova-plugin" at "2.6.0" for ios Failed to install
>   'onesignal-cordova-plugin': Error: pod: Command failed with exit code
>   1 at ChildProcess.whenDone
>   (/private/tmp/gimlet/1180294/project/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:169:23)
>   at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13) at maybeClose
>   (internal/child_process.js:962:16) at
>   Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
>   pod: Command failed with

In my **config.xml** I have:

```
<gap:plugin spec="https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Cordova-SDK.git" source="gif" />
```

I've also tried:

```
<gap:plugin spec="https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Cordova-SDK.git" source="npm" />
```

I'm not sure what else to try. The repo seems to be here still:

https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Cordova-SDK

The other main bits (versioning etc), are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id          = "org.chambresdhotes.app"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        versionCode = "23"
        version     = "1.3." >

    <!-- versionCode is optional and Android only -->

    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-9.0.0" />
```